# How to create a windows executable that does not require Vista/Win7 users to install the Visual C++ redistributable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have written a Java program that targets from Windows Vista to Windows 10.

The program runs on an embedded java runtime environment so the user doesn't have to fiddle with installing Java to get it to work. **The goal for this project is the user experience to be download -> run a single installer  -> run program *and have it feel native*. No other steps required by user.**

In order to accomplish this goal, I needed to write a native executable in C++ that invokes the JVM directly (rather than by calling java.exe) so the windows takbar feature pinning works right -- if I use an executable wrapper like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html) to pass execution off to java.exe at any point, then pinning doesn't work the way it's supposed to. My own executable needs to stay the running program for the duration in order for pinning to work right.

I have written a native launcher C++ program that uses JNI to invoke the Java Virtual Machine through `jvm.dll` instead of `java.exe` and it works. It is a 100 line shim (code at bottom of this post). It only imports `windows.h` and uses the following features: `HINSTANCE`, `GetProcAddress`, `WinMain`. It explicitly links against the embedded `jvm.dll` during runtime.

However, if I compile this shim using Visual Studio 2017, the resultant executable depends on the user having installed Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable. If they do not, the program gives the error ""can't start because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing from your computer".

**I have tried compiling this program using the /MT flag and also by selecting "Use MFC in a Static Library" in Visual Studio's General Project Property page. It did not make a difference; I get the same error regardless.**

Although many users on Windows Vista / Windows 7 will already have the runtimes installed, some may not, and my priority for this project is a smooth, error-free user experience from download through install to run.

I have no problem bundling additional dlls with my project.  I have no problem compiling with MinGW or Cygwin if that makes more sense. The only thing I want is some guaranteed path to `download -> install -> run` for any version of Windows from Vista to Windows 10.

How do I create an executable that stands alone or can be distributed along with a handful of dlls such that it is self-contained on Vista and newer version of Windows?

---

**Minimum Complete Verifiable Example:** [You can download a zip](http://hypnosplayer.org/debug/win-launcher.zip) or do everything manually yourself via the following steps:

**Step 1 - Initialize:** Create a folder `josh-problem`.

**Step 2 - Download JRE:** Download the [Windows 64 bit zip of Java 11](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html) and put it `josh-problem/jre` such that the contents of `josh-problem/jre` are the java folders named `lib`, `legal`, `jmods`, `include`, `conf`, `bin`, etc.

**Step 3 - Setup Java Program:** Create`josh-problem/src/net/joshuad/test/Main.java`.  Make its contents:

```
package net.joshuad.test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println ( "Hi from Java, launched via embedded jre, via native executable." );
    }
}
```

**Step 4 - Create Manifest** Create the file `josh-problem\MANIFEST.MF` with a single line content:

```
Main-Class: net.joshuad.test.Main
```

**Step 5 - Compile and create main.jar**: navigate to the folder `josh-problem` in cmd.exe. Run the following commands:

- `jre\bin\javac.exe -d bin src\net\joshuad\test\Main.java`
- `jre\bin\jar.exe cfm main.jar MANIFEST.MF -C bin .`

**Step 6 - Confirm jar works**: Run the command:

`jre\bin\java.exe -jar main.jar`

You should see the output: "Hi from Java, launched via embedded jre, via native executable."

**Step 7 - Compile Native Launcher** Create a project in Visual Studio 2017 and give it a single cpp file with the source code from the very bottom of this post.  Add to your includes `josh-problem\jre\include` and `josh-problem\jre\include\win32`.

**Step 8 - Try running** - Move the output executable into `josh-problem`. Try running the executable on a clean Windows 7 Service Pack 1 machine. It will give the error: "The program can't start because VCRUNTIME140D.dll is missing from your computer.".

**Step 9 - Run via java** - On the same clean Windows 7 computer run the program by invoking java.exe, it works.

`jre\bin\java.exe -jar main.jar`

**Step 10 - Install Visual C++ Redistributable and try our exe again** - Download and install the [2015 Visual C++ Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) on the clean Windows 7 machine. Try our executable again. It works.

**How do I compile this code so that it doesn't need the Visual C++ Redistributable? I know this is possible because we just demonstrated that java.exe is doing is. How do I make my program do it?*

**Downloads** I know this question is a mouthful. For your convenience, I have done the above work and put it [in a zip to download](http://hypnosplayer.org/debug/win-launcher.zip), which includes the jar, the java source, the C++ source, and the resultant executable.  You will have to download the jre using the above link to the jre folder; I didn't want to create a huge zip.

I've also uploaded my [visual studio project in a zip](http://hypnosplayer.org/debug/visualstudio-project.zip).

**win-launcher.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h> 
#include <windows.h>

typedef UINT(CALLBACK* JVMDLLFunction)(JavaVM**, void**, JavaVMInitArgs*);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    HINSTANCE jvmDLL = LoadLibrary(".\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");

    if (!jvmDLL) {
        printf("failed to find jvm.dll at specified location, exiting.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    JVMDLLFunction createJavaVMFunction = (JVMDLLFunction)GetProcAddress(jvmDLL, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

    if (!createJavaVMFunction) {
        printf("Failed to get pointer to JNI_CreateJavaVM function from jvm.dll, exiting\n");
        return 1;
    }

    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];

    int index = 0;
    options[index].optionString = (char *)"-Djava.class.path=./main.jar";

    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_10;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    createJavaVMFunction(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

    delete options;

    jmethodID main = NULL;
    jclass cls = NULL;

    cls = env->FindClass("net/joshuad/test/Main");
    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
        env->ExceptionClear();
        printf("Unable to find net.joshuad.hypnos.Main, exiting.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (cls != NULL) {
        main = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    }
    else {
        printf("Unable to find main() in java\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (main != NULL) {
        jclass classString = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
        jobjectArray argsToJava = env->NewObjectArray(argc - 1, classString, NULL);
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            printf("Converting: %s", argv[i]);
            jstring arg = env->NewStringUTF(argv[i]);
            env->SetObjectArrayElement(argsToJava, i - 1, arg);
        }

        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, main, argsToJava);

    }
    else {
        printf("main method not found");
    }

    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    return main(__argc, __argv);
}
```

Comment: You can't expect to slurp in such a massive dependency as VLC and not bleed a little.  Highly doubtful that an /MT build of the many VLC libraries is possible.

Comment: The dependency issue can't be arising from VLC or Java. It's definitely arising from our compiled exe.  You can run the program manually using the java.exe from the jre when there is no redistributables installed. I'll include the invocation above so you can confirm.

Comment: You can use dependency walker, or the modern equivalend ["dependencies"](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to verify if it's you exe itself or another library that is the issue

Comment: I have written a test program that removes all of the other libraries aside from the  jre and demonstrates the problem. Editing it into the main post now.

Comment: X/Y your real problem seems to be you want the process to be associated with the correct taskbar button/icon. Separate processes can share a button: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-setcurrentprocessexplicitappusermodelid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not with the exe you compiled but with the version of the jre you're using. Use another JRE version or compile your own version forked off of OpenJDK

[image]

Alternatively add `\jre\bin` to the library search path, since the DLL is located there.

For example with [`SetDllDirectoryA("jre\\bin")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya)

Comment: That's interesting. Why does java.exe succeed even when there's no redistributable installed given that's the case?

Comment: @JoshuaD because windows searches in the directory of the java.exe. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Comment: You are my favorite person on the whole internet, forever.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to target a specific SDK, just change "c++", "code generation", "runtime library" to "multi-threaded" or "multi-threaded debug" to statically link to the visual studio runtimes. This will make your application bigger but it will only depend on Windows DLLs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried that but it does not work. It generates a slightly larger exe, but still requires that the user install the 2015 visual studio runtime.

Comment: @JoshuaD Are you using other DLLs?

Comment: Yes, I am running against the java dll -- jvm.dll.

Comment: The error that occurs is "can't start because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing from your computer".  Practice machine is a freshly installed Windows 7 service pack 1, no VC++ runtimes installed.  If I install them, it works. If I uninstall, it doesn't work.  I tried setting /MT and also set "Use MFC in a Static Library", and also "Use MFC in a shared DLL". No combinations work.

Comment: using any static libraries?

Comment: No.  there are no .lib files in my project's folders anywhere.

Comment: but are you linking to any external static libraries like boost or poco?

Comment: No, definitely not.

Comment: Something you are linking to or building is compiled with "/MD", can't help much further without a [mcve]

Comment: Added to original post.

Comment: Also edited original post to make the question more clear / concise.

Comment: I see you are using precompiled headers, have you rebuilt those?

Comment: No. I have taken exactly the steps outlined in my post, plus fiddling with compiler settings.  I am not a C/C++ guy, so I have no experience recompiling headers. If you think that'll work I'll definitely give it a shot.

Comment: Maybe if you upload your project files and built executable we could see whats wrong

Comment: http://hypnosplayer.org/debug/win-launcher.zip. You'll have to download the jre and put it in the indicated folder.

Answer (score 1):

If your native code is small and uses only basic C standard library or Win32 functions, then you can get away with building with MinGW, which links with `msvcrt.dll` instead of `msvcr1xx.dll` for CRT calls so there won't be a dependency on VC++ DLLs (build with the `-static` flag to embed the libstdc++ in case you use C++ standard library functionality).

Otherwise just build with VC++ with the `/MT` flag. Your executable will become significantly bigger, but it's a more portable solution.

Comment: I have tried the /MT flag, it does not work for some reason. The executable in the link above was compiled with the /MT flag. I also tried compiling on MinGW. I got the same error popup without the redistributable runtime installed.